# how to get the Fuel UX search function fired

Tags: javascript, uisearchbar

I would like to use the Fuel UX search control.  I design a form as shown below to declare the Fuel Search control:

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="search input-group" role="search">
        <input type="search" id="searchprefix" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search Prefix">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

The search control is displayed as expected.  However, I don't know how to define the JavaScript function to be invoked when the user types search prefix inside the control and hit Enter.  Can someone show me a working example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define listener that will be triggered on pressing search (from fuel ux documentation):

**searched.fu.search** -- This event fires when a user presses Enter within the input or clicks the button.
**cleared.fu.search** -- This event fires when the user clears the input.
All search events are fired on the .search classed element.

**Example:**

Html code:

```
<div class="search input-group" role="search" id="mySearch">
  <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$('#mySearch').on('searched.fu.search', function(evt, data) {
    // data will then contain your search string .. in this place you have to place your search handler code
    alert(data);
});
```